# QApplication and main window connection

Tags: python, pyqt5

Considering a very basic *HelloWorld* PyQt5 application like:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 app')
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 80)
window.move(60, 15)

helloMsg = QLabel('<h1>Hello World!</h1>', parent=window)
helloMsg.move(60, 15)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It constructs a QApplication, a *parent-less* QWidget becoming the main window, adds a QLabel and shows it.

My question is: how does the QApplication know about the main window?
There is nothing in this code connecting the two.

Perhaps it is a naive question but just looking at this, it seems like magic.

How is the main window's paint event added to the application's event queue without telling so in the source code ? How does the QApplication instance know what is going to be added below in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

There's no "magic" involved: sub-modules can access their "main" modules, and each module of Qt can know if a QApplication instance is running.

### Long version

I think that's an interesting question, especially for those who are not *that* into low level programming. For instance, I've always given the QApplication as some sort of a "cartesian" assumption: «it exists».

As a premise, I'm not going to give you a very technical and low-level explanation: I don't have enough skills to do so (and I really welcome any other answer or edit to this), but I'm assuming that's not what you're looking for.

[Almost] technically speaking, you've to remember that Qt - and PyQt along with it - is an environment (the exact term is framework). As such, each one of its sub elements (classes, and eventually instances of them) "know" about that environment.
QApplication (and its base classes [QGuiApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) and [QCoreApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html)) is a class that is internally accessible from any "sub" Qt module.

It's something like the builtin types (`str`, `int`, `bool`, etc.) that are accessible to any module. For example, the `os.path` is a python module that you can import as standalone, but it *knows* what the main `os` module is, and each function of `os.path` actually uses some part of that main module.

Like most frameworks, Qt has what is called called an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), which is usually run as soon as you call `Q[*]Application.exec()`. An event loop is something that generally blocks itself waiting for something to happen (an event) and eventually react to it.

Whenever a Qt class needs it, it internally calls the `Q[*]Application.instance()` method to ensure that an instance of the application is running, meaning that an event loop is active and running. For example Qt widgets need that to be able to show the interface and interact with it: tell the operating system that a new window has been created, therefore it has to be drawn on the screen, so the OS will say "ok, let's show it" by sending Qt an event requesting the drawing, then Qt will "send" that event to that window that will finally draw itself by telling Qt how it's being painted; finally Qt will "tell" the OS what's going to be shown. At the same time, that window might need to know if some keyboard or mouse event has been sent to it and react in some way.

You can see this in the Qt sources: whenever a new QWidget is created, it ensures that a [QApplication exists](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/13e0a36626bd75e631dd9536e795a494432b1945/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L189) by calling [`QCoreApplication.instance()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/13e0a36626bd75e631dd9536e795a494432b1945/src/widgets/kernel/qapplication.h#L70).

The same happens for other Qt objects that require an application event loop running. This is the case of QTimer (that doesn't require a graphical interface, but has to interface with the system for correct timing) and QPixmap (which needs to know about the graphical environment to correctly show its image), but in some specific cases it also depends on the platform (for example, creation of a QIcon on MacOS requires a running event loop, while that's not necessary on Linux and Windows).

So, finally, that's what (roughly) happens when you run your code:

```
# create an application instance; at this point the loop is not "running"
# (but that might be enough to let know most classes about the current system
# environment, such as available desktop geometries or cursor position)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create a widget; an application exists and the widget can "begin" to create its
# interface using the information provided by it, like the system default font 
# (it's actually a bit more complicated due to cross-platform issues, but let's
# ignore those things now)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 app')
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 80)
window.move(60, 15)

helloMsg = QLabel('<h1>Hello World!</h1>', parent=window)
helloMsg.move(60, 15)

# "ask Qt to prepare" the window that is going to be shown; at this point the
# widget's window is not shown yet even if it's "flagged as shown" to Qt, meaning
# that "window.isVisible()" will return True even if it's not actually visible yet
window.show()

# start the event loop by running app.exec(); sys.exit will just "wait" for the
# application to return its value as soon as it actually exits, while in the
# meantime the "exec" function will run its loop almost as a "while True" cycle
# would do; at this point the loop will start telling the OS that a new window
# has to be mapped and wait from the system to tell what to do: it will probably
# "answer" that it's ok to show that window, then Qt will tell back the widget
# that it can go on by "polishing" (use the current style and app info to finally
# "fix" its size) and begin drawing itself, then Qt will give back those drawing
# information allowing the OS to actually "paint" it on the screen; then it will
# be probably waiting for some user (keyboard/mouse) interaction, but the event
# loop might also tell the OS that the window is willing to close itself (as a
# consequence of a QTimer calling "widget.close", for instance) which could
# possibly end with ending the whole event loop, which is the case of
# https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop
# which would also cause the application to, finally, return "0" to sys.exit()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The more direct answer is simple: `QApplication` starts a loop, which executes code related to every instance of `QWidget`. The magic part is the relationship between the application and the widgets, which is established behind the scenes. The fact that the two things are not related to each other in an obvious way is bad for a variety of reasons, but that's just how it is.